# Firechat changes route in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ngroute

I'm trying to implement Firechat in angularJS and have come across a weird issue.

After the chat initialises the angular route changes to the Firechat room name.

e.g I am initially on http://localhost/app/#/stream
and when firechat loads the route changes to
http://localhost/app/#/-KBLofTk2mb6AJCTSc5C

I can't seem to figure out how or why firechat is changing the route. Any advice would be great :)

Here is the code I am using to run fireChat:

```
$scope.goFireChat = function() {
    var chatRef = new Firebase('https://blazing-fire-3021.firebaseio.com'),
        target = document.getElementById("firechat-wrapper"),
        chat = new FirechatUI(chatRef, target);
    chatRef.onAuth(function(authData) {
        if (authData) {
            var userId = authData.uid,
                userName = "Anonymous" + userId.substr(10, 8);
            chat.setUser(userId, userName);

            $timeout(function() {
                chat._chat.enterRoom('-KBLofTk2mb6AJCTSc5C');
            }, 2000);
        } else {

            $timeout(function() {
                chat._chat.enterRoom('-KBLofTk2mb6AJCTSc5C');
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I do not have any knowledge in firechat, but `chat._chat.enterRoom('-KBLofTk2mb6AJCTSc5C');` is called in if and else statements. Are you sure that you meant it?

Comment: yeah that's intentional, it seems to be triggering the redirect before that though. When chatRef.onAuth is called.